# How to export full schema without any constraint issues for one month date range

Tags: oracle, import, export, datapump

I need to export the full schema of a one month data range. I have a lot of partitioned tables inside the schema, so I need a query to export a schema without any constraint issue or partitioned table issue.

Usually I use to take separate table mentioning all partitioned table names inside the query.

Comment: Please edit your question to include some more information. What you have tried so far? What exactly is your problem? What does your tables look like? You can have a look at [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do that (at least, not in a simple manner).

In order to export only part of every table, you'd have to use the `QUERY` parameter and include a `WHERE` clause to fetch data within the last month.

If there are many (actually, *more than one or two*) tables, I'd suggest you not to put everything into the command line, but to create a **parameter file**, put everything you use with EXPDP in there and use it later. It is easier to maintain.

Comment: I have lot of tables in a schema and how can we mention timestamp of one month of data for all mentioned tables , if some table has not a date column?

Comment: Exactly. How? Can you tell us? Suppose you've given a task "select number of rows inserted during the last month". How would you do that? **Can** you do that? What tells you that those rows were inserted *yesterday* or *a week ago*, if there's no such a column?

Comment: we can get from sysdate

Comment: OK then, please proceed to do so.